# How to add arrows (direction of the route) for Route in GMap.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, maps, gmap.net

I'm trying to add arrows to my route in GMap.NET, but I can't figure out how. I was easily able to change the color of the route, but I can't find anything about adding arrows.

Here's my current code:

```
route = new GMapRoute("Testing");
route.Stroke.Color = Color.Red;
topOverlay.Routes.Add(route);
route.Points.Add(latLng);
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code to display arrow

```
'Draw markers
Dim markersOverlay As GMapOverlay = New GMapOverlay("markers")
Dim marker0 As GMarkerGoogle = New GMarkerGoogle(Me.myMap.Position, GMarkerGoogleType.arrow)
Dim marker1 As GMarkerGoogle = New GMarkerGoogle(New PointLatLng(lat, lng), GMarkerGoogleType.arrow)
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker0)
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker1)
Me.myMap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay)
```

Hope this resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

Use following link of tutorial for GMap.NET

http://www.websofia.com/2013/02/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/

Comment: only link is less appreciated

Comment: It is not valid.